# truncating a file name - extension

Tags: basic4android

I have a file being loaded into fd.ChosenName and wondering if there is a quick solution such as an opposite to stringbuilder to truncate a file name (extension) for display purposes. So if the value of fd.ChosenName is picture1.jpg I could actually display the text picture1 in a panel etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.SubString2(0, str.LastIndexOf("."))
```

**Edited for correct answer**

SubString2 takes 2 parameters, beginIndex and endIndex

Reference: http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/core.html#string

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but I don't think this is valid in B4A?

Comment: It's not recognized in B4A - however B4A has something similar.

Comment: I apologize.  Evidently Basic4Android has a separate function: SubString2 that takes 2 parameters.  Just "SubString" takes 1 parameter (BeginIndex).  Updated original answer

Comment: Combing this with Length to get the length of the varying files did the trick. TY.